# Power set solution in **O(n) time** and **O(n) space** complexities?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, subset, subset-sum

Is it possible to find all possible subsets of set in  (i.e. power set) in  **O(n) time** and **O(n) space** complexities?

**Program in put** >> {a,b,c}

**Expected out put** in **O(n)** time and **O(n)** space complexity, here n is 3.

{}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {a,b}, {b,c}, {a,c}, {a,b,c}

Answer (score 6):

### Time-complexity

No. Time complexity will always be bounded below by the size of the output. Since the powerset of a set of size *n* has size *2<sup>n</sup>*, there exist no algorithm to find the powerset in less than *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*.

### Space-complexity

In term of *total* space, since the size of the output is *2<sup>n</sup>*, you cannot do any better than *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*.

Although in term of *auxiliary* space, given a set *s* of size *n*, any element of the powerset can be represented by a binary string of length *n*. Each position representing whether an element *x* of *s* is in the set.

By example, given the set `{a, b, c}`, the string `101` represents the subset `{a, c}`.

In particular since a binary string is a representation of an integer, you can define some order on your set and enumerate its elements. This requires, as intermediate storage, nothing but a single integer which, in size, takes no more than *O(n)*.

This is especially useful in languages implementing generators where you can traverse all the elements if the powerset with nearly no *auxiliary* storage.